# If I have multiple updates and inserts on multiple tables written one below the other in SQL, how do I optimise the code?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Code structure:

```
Public void Function() throws ioexcption

Update table a set values
Update table b set values
Insert into c values
Insert into d values
Many more updates and inserts

Function ends
```

How do I optimise the code? As the current code few minutes to complete when thousands of records  are there. Will stored procedures help or will indexing help?

Comment: Please add your code and not your code structure. We can't really help you with such a bare backbone.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.... But can't post the code... Against company policy.... So posting just structure....

Comment: @user1416631 how do you expect us to optimise your code when you cant show it to us?

Comment: Just asking if stored procedures or indexing will help

Comment: I think indexes will actually hurt in this situation with updates and inserts, because on adding any new row it needs to be indexed for every index, and changing any index column needs to change the rows place in the indexes that column belongs to

Answer (score 2):

Write all the changes in a file, read the file, parse every line, create a prepared statement, populate the parameters and execute it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.... But I need to check if any changes have occurred, if yes, update , else insert. And it has to work for thousands of rows, taking less time

Comment: Could you please give examples....

Comment: There are off the shelf projects that could help with it, Flyway for example (https://flywaydb.org/). Write your sql such that it checks if a row exist then perform an update, otherwise an insert. Then let Flyway run the script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... That's not allowed.... Just SQL ... That's it... Please tell me how to improve performance....

Comment: If you need to optimize the performance a stored procedure could help. Send a big array of structures describing the table, column names and values that have to be updated. Stored procedure then should make the decision when and what to insert or update and execute it really fast.

Comment: Thanks, How about having indexes... Will it optimise performance

Comment: It may, but you need to give it a try, test and measure to be sure.

Comment: Thanks.... Will give it a try

Comment: "can you please give examples".. oh the irony!

Comment: @user1416631 No, I think indexes will actually hurt in this situation with updates and inserts, because on adding any new row it needs to be indexed for every index, and changing any index column needs to change the rows place in the indexes that column belongs to.